# Mocking parameters of the function using pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

class_functions.py

```
#create object called some_application
#some_application is an object, and it's current session of an application
some_application=app.SessionStart()
class_functions:
    def PushScreenValue(some_application,"selectedvalue"):
        if some_application.header=="this_screen":
           some_application.send_values("selectvalue")
           some_application.selectAll()
           return True
        else:
         return False


How can I mock the parameter pytest python
```

```
test_class.py
```

#Here I am mocking some_application object that is sent as a parameter.I am also mocking  some_application.header,some_application.send_values and some_application.selectAll

```
from class_functions import class_functions



@pytest.mark.parametrize("some_application,"Value",expected", [(some_application,"Value",True)])
@mock.patch("class_functions.class_functions.mock_some_application.header")
@mock.patch("class_functions.class_functions.mock_some_application.send_values")
@mock.patch("class_functions.class_functions.mock_some_application.selectAll")
def test_PushScreenValue(mock_some_application,mock_some_application_header,mock_some_application_select,selectedvalue,expected):
  
  mock_some_application_header.return_value="this_screen"
  selectedvalue="Value"
   mock_some_application_send_values(selectedvalue)  #Sends the value to the app window
   mock_some_application_selectAll() #Selects the app window
   #checks there the function is rurning expected value
   assert class_functions_object.PushScreenValue(mock_some_application,selectedvalue)==expected
```

I am not sure how can I pass these mock objects properly in the test function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the class you are trying to test appears to have syntax errors. What I think it might look like is the following:

```
class functions:
    def PushScreenValue(self, some_application, val):
        if some_application.header=="this_screen":
            some_application.send_values(val)
            some_application.selectAll()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Now to test it, we don't need to create a bunch of patched objects. We only need one, which is for `some_application` since it has method calls on it. In that case we can simply use [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) which is just a sub-class of `Mock`.

As for the test, we only have two branches of logic to test, one where it returns `True` and one where it returns `False`. All that is left is for us to set up our two tests to hit each of these branches and to make assertions along the way. A possible assertion we could make when testing if the function returns `True` is to see if `some_application` does in fact call `send_values` with the value we are passing in. Illustrated below are the two tests which test your function and hit both logic branches.

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_pushscreen_success():
    klass = functions()
    app = MagicMock()
    app.header = "this_screen"

    screen_val = klass.PushScreenValue(app, "fizz")

    app.send_values.assert_called_with("fizz")
    app.selectAll.assert_called_once()
    assert screen_val


def test_pushscreen_fail():
    klass = functions()
    app = MagicMock()
    app.header = "foo"

    screen_val = klass.PushScreenValue(app, "fizz")
    assert screen_val is False
```

When I run it I get the following output:

```
===================================== test session starts =====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: *******
collected 2 items                                                                             

test_foo.py ..                                                                          [100%]

====================================== 2 passed in 0.06s ======================================
```